# React - Redux - Dispatch Action Error, this.props.mostrarProduto is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im dispatching 2 action on my container, but it keeps getting this.props.mostrarProduto() and this.props.esconderProduto() is not a function. The objective is to make a mouseover action to show and hide a component.

Thanks

**container Menu**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { mostrarProduto } from '../actions/index';
import { esconderProduto } from '../actions/index';

class Menu extends Component{

render(){
    return (
        <div onMouseOver={this.props.mostrarProduto()} onMouseLeave={this.props.esconderProduto()}>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    )
  }

}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {

return bindActionCreators({mostrarProduto, esconderProduto}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Menu);
```

**action index**

```
function mostrarProduto(){
    return {
        type: 'SHOW_PRODUCT'
    }
}

function esconderProduto(){
    return {
        type: 'HIDE_PRODUCT'
    }
}
```

**product reducer**

```
const productReducer = (state = false, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW_PRODUCT':
      return true;
    case 'HIDE_PRODUCT':
      return false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**reducer index**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import Produtos from './texto_produto';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    textoProdutos : Produtos
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not exporting the actions at all. You are using named imports, so the code should look like:

```
export function mostrarProduto(){
    return {
        type: 'SHOW_PRODUCT'
    }
}

export function esconderProduto(){
    return {
        type: 'HIDE_PRODUCT'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vlad, now im getting "Expected onMouseOver listener to be a function, instead got type object" :(

Comment: Thanks @vlad, i will try !

Comment: @HugoSeleiro I removed my message cause it wasn't correct. The problem is you're not passing a function reference to onMouseOver. Try `onMouseOver={this.props.mostrarProduto}` .

Comment: Thanks vlad, It Worked :D